# Proper way to section a text

Tags: sectioning

In WYSIWYG editors you press the return key to start a new section. In HTML terms a section of a text would be between `<p><\p>`. So what is the proper way to do the same in TEX?

I know there is `\section`. But how to section text of such section properly.

Example:

Desired Output:

> 1. Title
>
>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
>
>    erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
>
>    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam

So there is a section with title `Title` which holds a text which is separeted in three (abstract) sections.

Is it the proper way to wrap `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}` around each section? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: An empty line signifies a paragraph break.

Comment: Oh, okay didn't know that, thank you. Feeling bit stupid now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general way to end a paragraph is to add an empty line in the source:

```
This is a paragraph. And then some more text so that it extends over more than one line in the PDF.

This is a second paragraph.
```

There is also a TeX primitive `\par` that does the same, but an empty line is a much clearer way of denoting paragraph breaks in the text, so at least in the general text I would use that. In definitions of macros and environments `\par` can be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. And then some more text so that it extends over more than one line in the PDF.

This is a second paragraph.\par This is a third paragraph, but the paragraph break is a little `hidden'.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Torbjørn’s answer: There are some ways to change how LaTeX deals with such paragraphs in the output.

### change length registers

There are two lengths influencing the format of paragraph begins: 1. `\parindent` tells how much the first line of each paragraph is indented (except this following a sectioning macro, like `\section`) and 2. `\parskip` holds the vertical space before a new paragraph starts. both can be modified with `\setlength`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}% \baselineskip = distance bewteen two baselines

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. And then some more text so that it extends over more than one line in the PDF.

This is a second paragraph.\par This is a third paragraph, but the paragraph break is a little `hidden'.
\end{document}
```

[image: parskip]

### package `parskip`

The [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) basically does the same as above, but sets a noter value for `\parskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph. And then some more text so that it extends over more than one line in the PDF.

This is a second paragraph.\par This is a third paragraph, but the paragraph break is a little `hidden'.
\end{document}
```

### class options

Some classes provide similar functionality. The **[Koma-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes** have the option `parskip=no/half/full` (see manual for more), e.g.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
```

This will also set the indention to zero.